# Как отследить изменение значения QLable?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

Можно ли как-нибудь отследить менялся ли текст в `QLable`?

Comment: Приведите ваш пример, в котором надо отследить изменения Label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, например так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.labelOld = ''

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('lineEdit -> label', clicked=self.onClicked)

        box = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)       
        box.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        box.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 1, 0)
        box.addWidget(button, 1, 1)

        self._timer = QtCore.QTimer(self, interval=300)
        self._timer.timeout.connect(self.nevLabel)
        self._timer.start()

    def onClicked(self):
        self.label.setText(self.lineEdit.text())

    def nevLabel(self):
        if self.labelOld != self.label.text():
            self.labelOld = self.label.text() 
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Сообщение', 'Изменилось значение QLable!' )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, я тоже додумался до данного варианта(извините если грубо звучит), но мне нужно  чтобы это все отслеживалось без кнопок(моя ошибка что не уточнил)

Comment: @FOX_i_K при чем здесь кнопка ? За изменениями следит грубо говоря `timer`.  Приведите ваш пример, в котором надо отследить изменения Label.

Comment: Да, извините не вчитался в код, был занят другим вопросом. Спасибо за ответ